# How to assign a python matrix based on the product of the row and column of another matrix?

Tags: python, matrix

I have a matrix M that I intend to assign based on one condition checked on another matrix Q. The python code should assign 1 if the product of `i and j` of `Q` is greater than `0.5` else that index should be assigned 0. The code for both the first matrix and the second one is below

```
x=3
y=3
matx=[[0 for i in range(x)]for j in range(y)]
matx[0][0]=0.3
matx[0][1]=0.1
matx[0][2]=0.6
matx[1][0]=0.1
matx[1][1]=0.6
matx[1][2]=0.3
matx[2][0]=0.3
matx[2][1]=0.4
matx[2][2]=0.3
Q=matx
##check the product of the column and row of i and assign, am stuck below 
M=[[1 if ... else 0]]
```

Comment: Please describe your expected output, and provide some sample of what you mean by product of rows and columns. with all the values being smaller than 1, no product of any of these values will ever be greater than 5.

Comment: @AlainT. ,sorry just checked its supposed to be 0.5, editing

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny, Its `0.5`

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny, there is a way to assign a matrix based on the elements of the row of another matrix like I did when I initialized `matx` to zeros. You can implement a conditional structure in the loop to check and assign, that is where my problem is.

Comment: @I have no problem with the output even if it is zeros, the most important thing is to implement the structure, I will correct Q later

Comment: What do you mean the product of `i` and `j`, you need an i and a j to get one single value from `Q`. Do you mean the product of all three values in row `i` multiplied by the product of the other two values in column `j`?

Comment: @Erik McKelvey, exactly, that is what I need

Comment: Let me post the conjecture that I need, the conjecture is as follows  **=1
, if >0.5
, 0
otherwise**

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny, can you edit so it is on topic please, that is what I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I understood your question correctly, you can do it with loops by first calculating the product of each row and column, then looping through each element of the new matrix calculate the product of the row and column:

```
x=3
y=3
matx=[[0 for i in range(x)]for j in range(y)]
matx[0][0]=0.3
matx[0][1]=0.1
matx[0][2]=0.6
matx[1][0]=0.1
matx[1][1]=0.6
matx[1][2]=0.3
matx[2][0]=0.3
matx[2][1]=0.4
matx[2][2]=0.3
Q=matx

# Calculate row products
row_products = []
for i in range(x):
    product = 1
    for j in range(y):
        product *= Q[i][j]
    row_products.append(product)

# Calculate column products
column_products = []
for j in range(y):
    product = 1
    for i in range(x):
        product *= Q[i][j]
    column_products.append(product)

# Calculate matrix values
M=[[0 for i in range(x)]for j in range(y)]
for i in range(x):
    for j in range(y):
        if row_products[i] * column_products[j] / Q[i][j] > 0.5:
            M[i][j] = 1
```

Edit:

Since the question is unclear I am also leaving the solution for if `Q[i][j] > 0.5 -> M[i][j] = 1, otherwise M[i][j] = 0`, below:

```
x=3
y=3
matx=[[0 for i in range(x)]for j in range(y)]
matx[0][0]=0.3
matx[0][1]=0.1
matx[0][2]=0.6
matx[1][0]=0.1
matx[1][1]=0.6
matx[1][2]=0.3
matx[2][0]=0.3
matx[2][1]=0.4
matx[2][2]=0.3
Q=matx
M=[[0 for i in range(x)]for j in range(y)]
for i in range(x):
    for j in range(y):
        if Q[i][j] > 0.5:
            M[i][j] = 1
print(M)
```

Comment: Does it satisfy this conjecture? **=1
, if >0.5
, 0
otherwise?**

Comment: @KINYUATIMOTHYNJIRU If by Qij you mean the product of all the values in row i and column j

Comment: I realized Q[i][j] was counted in both the product of the row and the product of the column so I divided by that when calculating the final product

Comment: Okay, I got pure zeros for the output, isn't that weird? Though am marking this answer as accepted, I need M as an adjacent matrix for plotting a graph, it really needs to have 1s , maybe Qij means something else?

Comment: Okay, lemme use the updated code and check the output

Comment: Qij just means `Q[i][j]`

Comment: lemme acccept I will figure out the problem with my probability matrix later on

Answer (score 0):

Using the prod() function from the math module you can get the row and column products of the matrix and combine (cross product) them in a list comprehension:

```
Q = [[0.3, 0.1, 0.6],
     [0.1, 0.6, 0.3],
     [0.3, 0.4, 0.3]]

from math import prod

rProd = [*map(prod,Q)]         # row products
cProd = [*map(prod,zip(*Q))]   # column products
M = [int(r*c/Qij>0.5) for row,r in zip(Q,rProd) for Qij,c in zip(row,cProd)] 

print(M)
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

*Note that even with the division by Qij (which avoids having the Qij value twice in the product), the results will all be well below 0.5*

```
[r*c/Qij for row,r in zip(Q,rProd) for Qij,c in zip(row,cProd)]

[0.00054, 0.00432, 0.00162, 
 0.00162, 0.00072, 0.00324, 
 0.00108, 0.00216, 0.00648]
```